# split a passage into sentences, with delimiters: period, semicolon, and question marks

Tags: java, split, sentence

I am trying to split a passage of text into sentences with the delimiters (period, semicolon, and quesiton marks). I can think of using the split() method in java and save the resulting arrays into an ArrayList:

```
String[] sentencesByPeriod = passage.split("\\.");
String[] sentencesBySemicolon = passage.split("\\;");
String[] sentencesByQuestionM = passage.split("\\?");

List<String> allSentences = new ArrayList<String>();
allSentences.addAll(Arrays.asList(sentencesByPeriod));
allSentences.addAll(Arrays.asList(sentencesBySemicolon));
allSentences.addAll(Arrays.asList(sentencesByQuestionM));
```

This works, but I am wondering if there's any more efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: What makes you consider this inefficient?

Comment: the use of multiple String arrays and pushing them into an ArrayList seems very redundant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one regex you can do like this.

```
String s[] = passage.split("[.;?]");
List<String> allSentences = new ArrayList<String>();
allSenteces.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Or use an StringTokenizer

```
 StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(passage, ".;?");
 List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
 while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
  s.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
 }
```